# Refreshing a PHP Server Cache

Tags: php, caching, server-side-includes

I have a paypal listener in a directory on a site I maintain e.g. \paypal\listener.php

I have it set to write to a mysql database, but it is writing to my development environment instead of my production environment.

This is weird because I have a model e.g. DAO.php that controls all access to the database.  In other directories e.g. \directory2\page.php The page.php successfully writes to the production environment.

THE PROBLEM: To me this means that listener.php is including an old version of DAO.php (which is a class that was internally set to the development enviornment) In other directories though when this file is included the new version is being included.

Is it possible that one PHP implementation would server different versions of a file to different scripts??? If so how do I refresh the server cache that is making this happen?

I have already tried modifying and re-saving every relevant file to make the server think they are new.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Well, you could add the address of the server and the password of the root account to your question and I promise to investigate it ;) On a more serious note, after reading your question, I have no idea what is your system's architecture, what software are you using for caching (if you are using this at all) and what code you are executing. At least do some tests (modifications) in DAO.php, to see if it gets called at all. Maybe you can add some `var_dump`s in it or `file_put_content` (if you're not calling it from a browser) to see the internal state of the variables.

Comment: I sent an email to the server admin requesting a restart, but I don't have access to do that.  I don't know anything about the details of the architecture or any caching software we may be using.  I added a method to DAO.php to output some text and I got a fatal exception that the method does not exist, so its clearly the old version of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the server probably would have solved this issue, but that was not an option, the Server was a Microsoft IIS machine using application pools and refreshing the application pools solved the problem.